# GLEW based program does not compile

Tags: c++, opengl, gcc, g++, glew

I am trying to use GLEW in a program I'm creating, but my compiler will not compile it, instead it throws a ton of errors at this line `gcc -g -c glew.c -o glew.o`. This is my **Makefile**:

```
MY_LIBS = 
glewex: glew.o main.o glew.h
    g++ main.o glew.o glew.h -o glewex $(MY_LIBS)
glew.o: glew.c
    gcc -g -c glew.c -o glew.o
main.o: main.cpp
    g++ -g -c main.cpp -o main.o
```

It simply outputs hundreds of errors that look like this:

> __glewActiveTexture redeclared without dllimport attribute: previous import ignored [ -Wattributes ]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
gcc -g -DGLEW_STATIC -c glew.c -o glew.o
```

That should prevent DLL import/export decorations from getting added to the declarations.

Comment: It stopped my previous errors but now I am getting tons of errors that look like this: unknown name type 'PFNGLBUFFERREGIONENABLEDEXTPROC' warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]

Comment: Actually instead of messing with `-D` just plop a `#define GLEW_STATIC` down right after `#define __GLEW_H__` in `glew.h`.

Comment: Also, you need to continue compiling with `-DGLEW_STATIC` on your other source files. Whenever your other files `#include` any GLEW headers, you want to make sure you have the same `#define` affecting it each time.

Answer (score -2):

You don't want to add the library source files to the compiler input of your project. You should add the library to the list of linker inputs; either statically (libglew.a) or dynamic (-lglew).

I.e. either

```
gcc -o … -lglew
```

or

```
gcc -o … libglew.a
```

When linking GLEW statically you must add `-DGLEW_STATIC` to the compiler options generating the compilation units (.o files)

Comment: Quite the opposite. You DO want to add the source files to your project. Using an external library complicates the build and permanently binds your build to a specific version/architecture/release/compiler of the library. Since GLEW has a friendly license, it is 100% worth it to just compile it in.

Comment: @TheBuzzSaw: Nope. If you fear distribution problems, integrate the library into the project's build process as an external dependency. Just including the source files causes a lot of problems because you normally have an additional pre-build configuration step, which would be completely bypassed. As an example for this, download the Blender source file distribution. All 3rd party libraries are included, but built as real libraries during the project build process. And "compiling it in" means nothing else but "static linkage", but that should be done with a properly build library.

Comment: If you just include the naked source files you will end up in big trouble. Sooner or later (sooner actually).

Comment: I find it humorous that you compare something as small as GLEW to something as large as Blender. I am not promoting the idea that one should dump ALL external source code into a project. For GLEW, it is certainly a good idea.

Comment: @TheBuzzSaw: No, it's not. If you've got installed GLEW properly, you'll certainly have a static version of the library already present on the system. Either link that, or, if you're making so much use of it, add it as an external sub-build into your project. A matter of few seconds if you're organized well.